# ajax combo box appends any value I write into it to its dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, ajax, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

M using ajax combo box in my asp.net page, m bind it with my dataset from database, but i search something in it that value also gets bind , i want to disallow that

```
 <asp:ComboBox ID="ddlpro" runat="server" CssClass="simpletxt" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"  AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
                                                           onselectedindexchanged="ddlpro_SelectedIndexChanged" >
   </asp:ComboBox>
```

this works okay if i change

```
AppendDataBoundItems="false" to AppendDataBoundItems="true"
```

but my combo box in the gridview gives the above problem, which is not there otherwise out side the gridview

Answer (score 1):

Searched value never binds to the combo box you can check it by refreshing your page.

AutoCompleteMode - Determines how the ComboBox automatically completes the text that is typed into it. When "Suggest" is specified, the ComboBox will show the list, highlight the first matched item, and if necessary, scroll the list to show the highlighted item. If "Append" is specified, the ComboBox will append the remainder of the first matched item to the user-typed text and highlight the appended text. When "SuggestAppend" is specified, both of the above behaviors are applied. If "None" (the default value) is specified, the ComboBox's auto-complete behaviors are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="ddlsup" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList"           AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="false" >
```